# NodeJS and Mongo - Unexpected behaviors when multiple users send requests simultaneously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We've been using NodeJS and mongo (via mongoose) to do a very simple save(). We have a model called "highlights" which contains an array of ObjectId s that reference "responses."

This is the relevant segment of the highlight model declaration

```
var highlightSchema = Schema({
  [...]
  , responses: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Response'}]
  [...]
});
```

We insert a Response into a Highlight by first saving a Response object, then pushing it into an a Highlight object, and then saving the Highlight object. Very straightforward, as follows:

```
      Highlight.findOne({[...]}, function(err, highlight) {
        var response = new Response({[...]});
        response.save(function(err) {
          if(!err) {
            highlight.responses.push(response)
            highlight.save(function(err) {
              [...]
            })
          }
        });
      });
```

This works about 99%+ of the time exactly as expected. (note: you can safely assume that the 'highlight' variable in the above code does contain a valid Highlight object)

However, we are increasingly experiencing isolated problems during peak hours as many of this exact request is made simultaneously. In one case, a Response was created successfully, but a DIFFERENT Response was pushed into the highlight.responses array.

The timestamps of those two Responses showed that they were created about 30 milliseconds apart. Everything was created exactly as expected, except for the contents of the arrays inside the Highlight objects.

Since I'm currently also delving into a lot of operating systems stuff, my first thought was that this could be an issue with synchronization of some kind. But node is single-threaded, and I don't feel like I have a very good understanding of how nodejs's event loop works, nor am I even completely confident that that is the issue in the first place.

Please let me know if you have any ideas, or if I am explaining this clearly enough. I'm happy to elaborate.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling that the code you posted is NOT enough to understand where the issue is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into a concurrency issue. The way you have your schemas modeled will not ensure atomicity, hence the issues you're experiencing.

The best option to avoid such problems and to ensure atomicity, would be to nest the Responses model into the Highlights model.

This way you'd be working only with the Highlights model  by pushing a Response element directly into the Responses property of the Highlight model.

This is the only way to ensure atomicity with MongoDB.

So you'd have something like this:

```
   +----------------------+
   |  Highlight model     |
   +----------------------+
   | _id 1                |
   |                      |
   | property 1: 'abc'    |
   | property 2: 'bla'    |
   | property 3: 123      |
   | responses:[          |
   |   +----------------+ |
   |   | Response _id 1 | |
   |   +----------------+,|
   |   | Response _id 2 | |
   |   +----------------+,|
   |   | Response _id 3 | |
   |   +----------------+,|
   |   | Response _id n | |
   |   +----------------+]|
   +----------------------+
```

Not sure how you do it with Mongoose, but in the mongo shell if you wanted to add a response to the Highlight object with _id ObjectId('1234') you'd do something like this:

```
    db.highlights.update({_id: ObjectId('1234')},{$push:{Responses: {"Your response object"}}});
```

[$push reference from MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

I'm pretty sure that you must be able to acomplish this with Mongoose in a simpler way, probably just a matter of browsing it's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To nest the model you could write the Schema like this

```
const ResponseSchema = require('../where your schema file is')

var highlightSchema = Schema({
  [...]
  , responses: [ResponseSchema]
  [...]
});
```