# Mongoose difference between .save() and using update()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

To modify a field in an existing entry in mongoose, what is the difference between using

```
model = new Model([...])
model.field = 'new value';
model.save();
```

and this

```
Model.update({[...]}, {$set: {field: 'new value'});
```

The reason I'm asking this question is because of someone's suggestion to an issue I posted yesterday: [NodeJS and Mongo - Unexpected behaviors when multiple users send requests simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262114/nodejs-and-mongo-unexpected-behaviors-when-multiple-users-send-requests-simult). The person suggested to use update instead of save, and I'm not yet completely sure why it would make a difference.

Thanks!

Comment: I often think one of the great strengths of open source is that you can "step into" the library and see how it ticks. The Mongoose docs even have a "show source" link for many functions.

Comment: `model = new Model(...)` isn't going to update anything, because it creates a new document. I think the question would be better without that confusion.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Two concepts first. Your application is the **Client**, Mongodb is the **Server**.

The main difference is that with `.save()` you already have an object in your client side code or had to retrieve the data from the server before you are writing it back, and you are writing back the whole thing.

On the other hand `.update()` does **not** require the data to be loaded to the client from the server. All of the interaction happens server side without retrieving to the client.So `.update()` can be very efficient in this way when you are adding content to existing documents.

In addition, there is the `multi` parameter to `.update()` that allows the actions to be performed on more than one document that matches the query condition.

There are some things in convenience methods that you lose when using `.update()` as a call, but the benefits for certain operations is the "trade-off" you have to bear. For more information on this, and the options available, see the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update).

In short `.save()` is a client side interface, `.update()` is  server side.

Comment: This is a GREAT answer. You gave *context* information, which is exactly what usually is missing from top-grade guides and tutorials...

Comment: one other `multi` parameter I found useful, and which actually led me to this question, is `upsert` (boolean, defaults to false) which when set to true, automatically creates a new document when the query condition is not met.

Comment: Another useful thing to know is that save() triggers the default validations while update requires you to turn runValidators on. But even in that case runValidators will only come into effect if you use certain keywords
(http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators):

"One final detail worth noting: update validators only run on $set and 
$unset operations (and $push and $addToSet in >= 4.8.0). For 
instance, the below update will succeed, regardless of the value of 
number, because update validators ignore $inc."

Comment: **IMPORTANT NOTE** `.save()` does **not** “_write back **the whole thing**_”; it diffs the document and only sends the fields that have actually changed. So it is okay to be used to make a _tiny_ change on the database, as with `.update()`.

Comment: @iss42 
 Here it is. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/b5b3053fa2207b4bdea0092db5350d455accfbb1/benchmarks/benchjs/update.js#L204-L207

Comment: @K **You're missing the point**. In order to `.save()` you have to have retrieved the data "over the wire" and back to the client. As the the first line in the answer says, there is a distinct different in concepts. For **performance** reasons you simply call `.update()` and don't pull the data first, or have "schema hooks" or any of that, and simply tell the database what to update and it does it. Besides, you're linking to a "comment" and not the actual coded implementation, and the actual implementation of "diffing" is ... Erm not really reliable at best. So overwriting can happen.

Comment: Another behavior that I've noticed between the difference of `.save()` vs `.update()` is when saving, the defaults you set in your schema get added to the document if they're missing. At least as of version 5.2.4.

Answer (score 51):

Some differences:

- As noted elsewhere, `update` is more efficient than `find` followed by `save` because it avoids loading the whole document.
- A Mongoose `update` translates into a MongoDB `update` but a Mongoose `save` is converted into either a MongoDB `insert` (for a new document) or an `update`.
- It's important to note that on `save`, [Mongoose internally diffs the document](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/168f516902bf142006581479d58d19867fb844e8/lib/model.js#L146) and only sends the fields that have actually changed. This is good for atomicity.
- By default [validation is not run](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-version-40-mongoose-nodejs-odm) on `update` but it can be enabled.
- The middleware API (`pre` and `post` hooks) is different.

Comment: Tip of the hat to ya

Answer (score 19):

There is a useful feature on Mongoose called Middleware. There are 'pre' and 'post' middleware. The middlewares get executed when you do a 'save', but not during 'update'. For example, if you want to hash a password in the User schema everytime the password is modified, you can use the pre to do it as follows. Another useful example is to set the lastModified for each document. The documentation can be found at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
var user = this;
// only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
if (!user.isModified('password')) {
    console.log('password not modified');
    return next();
}
console.log('password modified');
// generate a salt
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }

    // hash the password along with our new salt
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});
});
```

Comment: As of Mongoose 4.0, query middleware is also supported (e.g. for `update`).

Comment: +1 Thanks for `user.isModified('password')` bit. This was driving me crazy. Every time I was trying to save something, passwords was changing.

Answer (score 16):

One detail that should not be taken lightly: **concurrency**

As previously mentioned, when doing a `doc.save()`, you have to load a document into memory first, then modify it, and finally, `doc.save()` the changes to the MongoDB server.

The issue arises when a document is edited that way **concurrently**:

- Person A loads the document (v1)
- Person B loads the document (v1)
- Person B saves changes to the document (it is now v2)
- Person A saves changes to an outdated (v1) document
- Person A will see Mongoose throw a VersionError because the document has changed since last loaded from the collection

Concurrency is not an issue when doing atomic operations like `Model.updateOne()`, because the operation is done entirely in the MongoDB server, which performs a certain degree of **[concurrency control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/)**.

Therefore, beware!

Comment: In this case, are there companies that only use atomic operations like Model.updateOne() then? Or is it just something to keep in mind? I find it difficult to use atomic operations when I need to query the document first for conditional changes. Just curious if I should keep struggling to only use atomic, or be okay with using a combination of both, keeping in mind to use atomic whenever possible.