# Mongoose change document _id on save/update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

a quick one:

Why is Mongoose change/upgrading the _id field of a document when I push an update?
Is this an intended behavior?

Thanks.

This is the update I use inside my PUT route, and it returns successfully the updated model, but unfortunately with a new _id for doc

```
Document.findById(req.params.doc_id, function (err, doc) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err)

    // Do some subdoc stuff here …

    doc.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Success!');
            res.json(doc);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it's actually an update? It shouldn't be changing the _id. This would be easier to figure out with some code.

Comment: Sorry someone down voted you dude, wasn't me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, problem solved:
I was logging the wrong _id (doh!)

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose docs http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/model-definition.html
suggest using `update` or `findOne`

ex:

```
var query = { name: 'borne' };
Document.update({"_id": req.params.doc_id}, { name: 'jason borne' }, {}, function(err, numAffected){
  if (!err) {
    console.log('Success!');
    res.json(numAffected);
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

or

```
Model.findOne({ "_id": req.params.doc_id }, function (err, doc){
  doc.name = 'jason borne';
  doc.save();
  // here you could use your save instead, but try not to use the doc again
  // it is confusing
  // doc.save(function (err, documentSaved, numberAffected) {
  //   if (!err) {
  //     console.log('Success!');
  //     res.json(documentSaved);
  //   } else {
  //     console.log(err);
  //   }
  // });
});
```

Later I also found the findById update suggested in some docs http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html, which seems to be up to date, check the version you are using and also double check the two times you are using `doc` in your functions here. Also you can check your mongoDB and see if there are more than one record getting saved.

```
db.documents.find( {} )
```

Comment: Hi. Well, 2.7 is outdate and I use 3.8.* of Mongoose.

As for save and update, it really depends: I mostly use Mongoose middleware (pre/post) on save to hash a password interim.

This post describes that nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278761/mongoose-difference-between-save-and-using-update