# Mongo/MongooseJS Object model doesn't save correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My schema is set up with this as one of its fields:

```
var recSchema = mongoose.Schema({    
   //some fields here
   plan    : {},
   //some other fields here
```

I've noticed this in a couple of instances; if a record already has an object in the `plan` field, then when I do something like this:

```
   Rec.findById(id, function(err, doc){
     doc.plan.type = 'active';
     doc.data = [// some stuff];
     doc.save(function(err){
       if(err){console.log(err)}else{
         // it should have worked 
       }
     })
   })
```

When I do that, the record is NOT updated. This only happens when there is already something in the `doc.plans` object; I can set it once and then not change it after that.

What am I doing wrong here, and how do I rectify it?

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: @MuliYulzary I've edited the question, it seems to only happen when there's already something in the `plans` object, not when it's unset.

Comment: have you tried `Document.update()`?

Comment: @MuliYulzary Will give it a go, although for literally every other operation `document.save()` works just fine so I can't see how this would be any different, as per this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278761/mongoose-difference-between-save-and-using-update

Comment: @JohnnyHK Ah, yes that's fixed it. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll mark as correct.

Comment: Great. I'll just close it as a dupe.