# MongoDB Best way to pair and delete sequential database entries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, mean-stack

Okay so let's say I'm making a game of blind war!
Users A & B have x amount of soldiers

There are currently 0 DB docs.

User A sends 50 soldiers making a DB doc 
User B sends 62 soldiers after user A!

This creates a new DB doc.

I need the most effective/scalable way to lookup user A's doc, compare it to User B's doc then delete both docs! (After returning the result of course)

Here's the problem! I could potentially have 10,000+ users sending soldiers at relatively the same time! How can I successfully complete the above process without overlapping?

I'm using the MEANstack for development so I'm not limited to doing this in the database but obviously the WebApp has to be 100% secure!

If you need any additional info or explanation please let me know and I'll update this question

-Thanks

Comment: Here is a question to watch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262114/nodejs-and-mongo-unexpected-behaviors-when-multiple-users-send-requests-simult

Comment: compare 2 docs in what way?

Comment: Compare as in: look at the troops value of each doc! Effectively paring them in order. Aka doc 1 with 2 (return winner = doc 1, delete both) doc 3 with 4 (return winner = doc 4, delete both)

Comment: This seems lacking a bit by being just too minimal. I think first you need to explain how you are going to store these "moves" for "A" and "B", and clearly explain how you know they are playing against each other. Otherwise this becomes a very broad question where eberyones opinion will be different.

Comment: The point of the game is to be minimal! There are no accounts just users based on sessions. The game currently used restful calls to play. Every user is basically playing against the user before them. If the user before them sent 20 troops they would have send more than 20 to win but don't know how many the user before them sent!

Comment: @dollarVar I actually think the answer is a bit different from the question being asked in this case. But if you are considering a similar problem, then the answer I have supplied may be of some worth for you as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn Hey, thanks for the notification. And great answer! However frankly I do not have any similar problems at all yet, I am still standing before "*no* prepared statements, but [`.eval()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/)". (off topic;)

Comment: Have you had some time to digest this. The general case is that rather than having a long and protracted discussion about concurrency that will not resolve anything, is to say "Hey, there is actually another way of solving your problem". Even though it may not be a direct answer, it is valid. Most importantly it meets the specs of what you wish to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind here is you may not need to do all the work that you think you need to, and your problem can probably be solved with a little help from [TTL Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/) and possibly [capped collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/). Consider the following entries:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("531cf5f3ba53b9dd07756bb7"), "user" : "A", "units" : 50 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("531cf622ba53b9dd07756bb9"), "user" : "B", "units" : 62 }
```

So there are two entries and you got that `_id` value back when you inserted. So at start, "A" had no-one to play against, but the entry for "B" will play against the one before it.

ObejctId's are [monotonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), which means that the "next" one along is **always** greater in value from the last. So with the inserted data, just do this:

```
db.moves.find({ 
    _id: {$lt: ObjectId("531cf622ba53b9dd07756bb9") }, 
    user: { $ne: "B" } 
}).limit(1)
```

That gives the preceding inserted "move" to the current move that was just made, and does this because **anything** that was previously inserted will have an `_id` with *less value* than the current item. You also make sure that you are not "playing" against the user's own move, and of course you limit the result to one document only.

So the "moves" will be forever moving forward, When the next insert is made by user "C" they get the "move" from user "B", and then user "A" would get the "move" from user "C", and so on.

All that "could" happen here is that "B" make the **next** "move" in sequence, and you would pick up the same document as in the last request. But that is a point for **your** "session" design, to store the last "result" and make sure that you didn't get the same thing back, and as such, deal with that however **you** want to in your design.

That should be enough to "play" with. But let's get to your "**deletion**" part.

Naturally you "think" you want to delete things, but back to my initial "helpers" this should not be necessary. From above, deletion becomes only a factor of "cleaning-up", so your collection does not grow to massive proportions.

If you applied a TTL index,in much the same way as [this tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) explains, your collection entries will be cleaned up for you, and removed after a certain period of time.

Also what can be done, and especially considering that we are using the *increasing* nature of the `_id` key and that this is more or less a "queue" in nature, you could possibly apply this as a [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/). So you can set a maximum size to how many "moves" you will **keep** at any given time.

Combining the two together, you get something that only "grows" to a certain size, and will be automatically cleaned for you, should activity slow down a bit. And that's going to keep all of the operations **fast**.

Bottom line is that the concurrency of "**deletes**" that you were worried about has been removed by actually "removing" the need to delete the documents that were just played. The query keeps it simple, and the TTL index and capped collection look after you data management for you.

So there you have what is my take on a very concurrent game of "Blind War".

Comment: Hey! Actually I think this solution is almost perfect for what I need and I almost accepted it yesterday! However the problem is this. The troops being sent are pooled. Then the winner recieve x amount of troops back from that pool. So if user b plays user a and user c plays userb then the pool of troops would have over withdrawn since user b own and his troops are no longer in the central pool! Is there a way to apply your answer above so that only two users are ever matched?

Comment: @gbachik What I wanted to display here what given the context of your question, and that it relied on working with "pairs" of documents, that the concurrency issues with updates and deletes could be avoided and achieve the same result. So this serves as answering that. Your **new** problem is an interesting one, yet something comes to mind about notifying players of "wins/losses" as it were from the material I gave you. Think on that, and it still eludes you, then you can always ask **another** question.

Comment: True! I made another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316027/mongodb-mongoose-how-do-i-pair-two-db-entries-without-conflicts