# MongoDB/Mongoose How do I pair two db entries without conflicts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

Refer to this question for additional info:

[MongoDB Best way to pair and delete sequential database entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289178/mongodb-best-way-to-pair-and-delete-sequential-database-entries)

---

Okay so I'm making a game of "blind war" if you will! 
Basically it works like this:

There are 10,000 users playing at one time.
There are no user accounts only an alias they choose upon visiting my website.
A user is given a random amount of troops on visit.
A user can submit any amount of their troops to go to "blind war".

The game works like this: 
User A submits x amount of troops. (say 100)
User B submits x amount of troops.(say 72)
(all these troops are held in the "giant pool of troops")

The application pairs these two users.
User A wins and given pack his troops plus user Bs troops. (aka 172 troops)
User B loses and is given back nothing.

Here's my problem:
I could potentially have 2,000 users submitting troops at relatively the same time!
I need to make sure that three or more users are never matched on accident!

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
Duels
.Where('_id').lt('objectId')
.Where('User').ne('A')
.exec(callback)

function callback(err,doc){
  /* Do troops comparison & other stuff here */
  doc.remove

};
```

but I'm afraid this may end up in docs grabbing two of the same doc before removing. 
Causing the pool of troops to be overdrawn...

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: I would just have a collection of current matches

Comment: Or better yet, just have each user have a current match count.

Comment: Actually looking at the answer I submitted, you would **never** get back more than 2 results. I think your real problem here is maintaining the "troop" counts between players

Comment: I think by the way this question has been worded you still are not really grasping the content of the previous answer. So the answer here goes further into explaining how you use that in your "game resolving" part. Also as indicated by the code above (which is not the same statement you were given) You are still **hanging on** to the idea of deleting documents. You **don't need** to delete documents with this pattern. Read through both, and ask questions on  the answer if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from my [original response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22290957/2313887), this is again something where some different thinking can come to your aid. And as such this seems to be more about architecture than saying that implementing  your code "in a certain way" is going to be the best way to go.

From your comment on that and your question here, it seems that the problem you need to solve is how to adjust the count of troops for the **other** user playing the move. Let's get started by looking at the same data again:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("531cf5f3ba53b9dd07756bb7"), "user" : "A", "units" : 50 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("531cf622ba53b9dd07756bb9"), "user" : "B", "units" : 62 }
```

---

### Making the "move"

So the situation here is that user "B" has just made their move and committed `62` units in that move. In the prior post I explained how to get back the move for the matching user "A", and therefore you can "pair" them and determine the win.

Taking that further, consider what happened in the request. User "B" submitted, then you insert the document for their move, then you read back the matching one. So right now you have both documents in memory for the request. If you consider the session data, then you might have something like this (in a very brief way):

```js
{
    currentUnits: 100
}
```

Let's call that the starting count. So when you **submit** a move from the user, you just decrement the count of troops they have. So when doing the **insert** of `62` troops, the counter goes to this:

```js
{
    currentUnits: 38
}
```

That's good practice, as you do that on the insert acknowledgement within the move. But next up inside that callback you are going to do the find as I said, and that **only** returns one document. Now you have the information you can compare and do your math. User "B" wins so you can adjust your session value:

```js
{
    currentUnits: 150
}
```

So that should cover everything for the move for user "B". You took away units when a move was played, you matched the other player, then you "did the math" and adjust your results. Done! Oh, and you did **save** all the session data in a persistent store didn't you? Nod yes. And also that session data is tied to the user handle (or the user is in fact the session id) in order to gain access to modifying it.

All that is left is to "notify" the other player.

---

### Telling someone else the news

This part should be simple. So I'm not coding it up for you. You are using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for your application, so all this comes down to is sending a message. That means the data you "emit" tells the other user on the client that they "lost their troops", however you want to deal with it. But also remember that you "took away" those units when **their move** was submitted. In all cases that is making sure no-one can commit more than they have.

The only possible thing to talk about here is **scaling** your application beyond one instance. So you can talk happily with events on "node" all working on one server instance, but to "scale" you would need to pass messages in between different instances.

One way to handle this using MongoDB can be with a [capped collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/).

Aside from what capped collections generally do in the manner of keeping a **set** size for a collection of documents, there is one more thing they offer, and that is a [tailable cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/#tailable-cursor). A fairly atypical way to create one with the node driver would be like:

```
var options = { tailable: true, awaitdata: true, numberOfRetries: -1 };
var cursor = collection.find(query, options).sort({ $natural: 1 });
```

The full options are listed in the [Cursor()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) section of the driver manual page. You can get at these "native" methods in mongoose by the typical way.

What a "tailable" cursor is set up to do is to "follow" the "last inserted" document in the collection and you can sit and "follow" in this way with an even poll, much as in:

```
    (function more() {
        cursor.nextObject(handle(function(doc) {
            if (!doc) return setTimeout(poll, self.wait);

            callback(doc);
            latest = doc._id;
            more();
        }));
    })();
```

So within such a construct you "find" the newly inserted document and pass to your inner callback the information to be processed, where you "send" messages to clients, update things and whatever else you want to do.

Back to you actual "request", then you would be issuing an insert after you "did your math" to the separate "capped collection". You would want something meaningful by brief like:

```
{ "player": "B", "vsplayer": "A", "win": 50, "loss": 62 }
```

And again these are **just** inserts. So you would set up a [TTL index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) to handle the deletions over time and being capped, the old entries would naturally drain by being "pushed out" of the entries present in the collection.

On your "client" side, each connected user application keeps track of the "last _id" value reveived. So the newly inserted entries are **always** greater in value to the "older" previous ones.

So there is "one way" to use MongoDB to create a persistent queue that you can sequentially process in order to share message passing amongst multiple application server instances.

---

### Final Words

With all said for implementing a "tail-able" cursor in this way, for my money I would be using [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) or something much the like. But you might find the MongoDB method to be more suited to you if you don't want to delve into another technology. Or perhaps this sort of "scalability" is not needed by your application (at least at this stage) and simply passing of to "socket.io" methods within the request would be enough. Up to you.

Largely though, you still seem to be "hung-up" on your concepts of "paring" and "deleting". This was the intention to cover in the last response and was to say that **deleting** of documents when they are processed is **not required**. The process described **ensures** that you never get the *"same pair"* back on any request.

I would encourage you to *"re-read"* that information and really understand the process. And ask if you have questions. From what has been discussed there, the analogy of you data access pattern is more like "playing off a stack" than "matching pairs".

So what you were given in response, *following on* with the logic described here is **all** you should need in order to set up your data access patterns. Your other component will be of course the messaging, but this gives you access to the data that you need.